# C++ - EncryptMessage not encrypting the correct data

Tags: c++, windows, ssl

I've been following this tutorial for SSL/TLS online (well its more of reading the guys source code and following along) but I've hit a bumpy road with this EncryptMessage part because it pushes the data out of the way and encrypts the wrong info.

The pbloBuffer that I send it is:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
HOST: www.google.com\r\n\r\n
```

But when I do pbMessage = pbloBuffer + Sizes.cbHeader; I end up with (even the microsoft websites says to do this)

```
1\r\n
HOST: www.google.com\r\n\r\n
```

Now pbMessage is the code above, and that's inserted under SECBUFFER_DATA so it's not even getting the full data. From what I understand SECBUFFER_DATA is the "user" data that the Webserver will decode and process.

Can you find out how to fix this and properly send the encrypted data?

Full source: (This code is experimental as I am trying to understand it before I makes changes)

```
    int Adaptify::EncryptSend(PBYTE pbloBuffer, int Size) {

    SECURITY_STATUS    scRet{ 0 };
    SecBufferDesc      Message{ 0 };
    SecBuffer          Buffers[4]{ 0 };
    DWORD              cbMessage = 0, cbData = 0;
    PBYTE              pbMessage = nullptr;
    SecPkgContext_StreamSizes Sizes = { 0 };
    QueryContextAttributesW(&hContext, SECPKG_ATTR_STREAM_SIZES, &Sizes);

    pbMessage = pbloBuffer + Sizes.cbHeader;
    cbMessage = (DWORD)strlen((const char*)pbMessage);

    Buffers[0].BufferType = SECBUFFER_STREAM_HEADER;
    Buffers[0].cbBuffer = Sizes.cbHeader;
    Buffers[0].pvBuffer = pbloBuffer;

    Buffers[1].BufferType = SECBUFFER_DATA;
    Buffers[1].pvBuffer = pbMessage;
    Buffers[1].cbBuffer = cbMessage;

    Buffers[2].BufferType = SECBUFFER_STREAM_TRAILER;
    Buffers[2].cbBuffer = Sizes.cbTrailer;
    Buffers[2].pvBuffer = pbMessage + cbMessage;

    Buffers[3].BufferType = SECBUFFER_EMPTY;
    Buffers[3].cbBuffer = SECBUFFER_EMPTY;
    Buffers[3].pvBuffer = SECBUFFER_EMPTY;

    Message.cBuffers = 4;
    Message.pBuffers = Buffers;
    Message.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION;

    scRet = EncryptMessage(&hContext, 0, &Message, 0);
    if (send(hSocket, (const char*)pbloBuffer, Buffers[0].cbBuffer + Buffers[1].cbBuffer + Buffers[2].cbBuffer, 0) < 0) {
        MessageBox(0, L"Send error", 0, 0);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first - you need call `QueryContextAttributesW` only once after `InitializeSecurityContextW` return `SEC_E_OK` - no sense call it every time, when you need send data. and save result. say inherit your class from `SecPkgContext_StreamSizes` - `class Adaptify : SecPkgContext_StreamSizes;` and call on end handshake (once) `QueryContextAttributesW(&hContext, SECPKG_ATTR_STREAM_SIZES, this);`

about send send data - in your case `Buffers[1].pvBuffer` of course must point to your actual data `pbloBuffer` but not to `pbloBuffer + Sizes.cbHeader` code can be like this:

```
int Adaptify::EncryptSend(PBYTE pbloBuffer, int Size) {

    SECURITY_STATUS ss = SEC_E_INSUFFICIENT_MEMORY;

    if (PBYTE Buffer = new BYTE[cbHeader + Size + cbTrailer]) {

        memcpy(Buffer + cbHeader, pbloBuffer, Size);

        SecBuffer sb[4] = {
            { cbHeader, SECBUFFER_STREAM_HEADER, Buffer},
            { Size, SECBUFFER_DATA, Buffer + cbHeader},
            { cbTrailer, SECBUFFER_STREAM_TRAILER, Buffer + cbHeader + Size},
        };

        SecBufferDesc sbd = { 
            SECBUFFER_VERSION, 4, sb
        };

        if (SEC_E_OK == (ss = ::EncryptMessage(this, 0, &sbd, 0)))) {
            if (SOCKET_ERROR == send(hSocket, (const char*)Buffer, sb[0].cbBuffer+sb[1].cbBuffer+sb[2].cbBuffer+sb[3].cbBuffer, 0)) 
                ss = WSAGetLastError();
        }
        delete [] Buffer;
    }
    return ss;
}
```

so you need allocate new buffer with `cbHeader + Size + cbTrailer` size (wher `Size` is your actual message `Size` and copy your message at `Buffer + cbHeader`

Comment: Thank you! (I was reading through the guys source code and I found out he shifts everything over before he even calls the SendEncrypt function. 

I appreciate your help.